# The new line before the parenthesis character

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, newline

I have an string array data like this:

```
GAZIOSMANPASA-KARADENIZ (ISTANBUL)
```

i want to before each parenthesis a sub down the line, like this:

```
GAZIOSMANPASA-KARADENIZ 

(ISTANBUL)
```

and then i want to write textblock. How or what can I do? I'd appreciate it if you could give an example.

Comment: You've tagged your question with `regex`. Which pattern did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "sub down the line"?

Comment: @SumnerEvans Sorry, i made a mistake when writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `String.Replace` method to insert line breaks (`Environment.NewLine`) before each parenthesis and then assign result to `TextBlock.Text` property (or to a view model property which used in a binding)

```
string text = "GAZIOSMANPASA-KARADENIZ (ISTANBUL)";
textBlock.Text = text.Replace(" (", Environment.NewLine +"(");
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require Regular Expressions. Just use [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string text = "GAZIOSMANPASA-KARADENIZ (ISTANBUL)";

string part1 = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf('('));
string city = text.Substring(text.IndexOf('('));

Console.WriteLine(part1);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(city);
```

**Output:**

```
GAZIOSMANPASA-KARADENIZ 

(ISTANBUL)
```

**Here's a [working .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8Ezq9)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str =  "GAZIOSMANPASA - KARADENIZ(ISTANBUL)";
str = str.Insert(str.IndexOf('('), "\n");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

You can insert a new line(`\n`) at the index of `(`.